# Zero One loss function in Tensor Flow

Tags: tensorflow

I was checking for default implementation of Zero-One loss in Tensor Flow libraries to measure accuracy of binary classification . I couldn't find one. Can some one point me to the right resource to find that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have as inputs:

- `y_pred`: your predictions. Tensor of shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`, values in `[0., 1.]`
- `y_true`: the true values. Tensor of same shape, binary values 0 or 1

You can compute your loss and accuracy with:

```py
y_pred_binary = tf.round(y_pred)
temp = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_pred_binary, y_true), tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(temp, 1)
batch_loss = tf.reduce_sum(temp)
```

Bear in mind that `batch_loss` does not have gradients so you cannot optimize on that loss. Instead, you could use sigmoid cross entropy.